# How to get list of table counts in GBQ regardless if table is empty

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this SQL Statement that provides a row count for all tables in a `in` clause:

```
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table, nullif(count(*),0) as count FROM `mydataset.*`
where _TABLE_SUFFIX in (
"TABLEA"
, "TABLEB"
, "TABLEC"
)
group by _TABLE_SUFFIX
order by _TABLE_SUFFIX
```

`TABLEB` is NULL. I know this going in.  But the output ignores `TableB` because it's considered empty.

the response I get is:

```
TABLE, COUNT
TABLEA, 315
TABLEC, 123
```

I need:

```
TABLE, COUNT
TABLEA, 315
TABLEB, 0
TABLEC, 123
```

any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQL Statement that provides a row count for all tables in a in clause

Try below - for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  table_id,
  row_count
FROM `myproject.mydataset.__TABLES__`
WHERE table_id IN ('TABLEA', 'TABLEB', 'TABLEC')
```

Comment: brilliant sir.  Thank you very much